# Convert object containing objects to array containing objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a JSON object that will sometimes be an object (a single instance) and sometimes be an array (multiple instances of the object). I need to write an if statement that basically says if this section of JSON is an object, wrap it in an array containing that single object, and if it's an array containing multiple objects, return that array. In either instance I'm returning an array containing either 1 or multiple objects.
Here is what the JSON looks like when it is NOT an array.

```
"link": {
  "values": {
    "key1": "value1",
    ...
    "key8": "value8"
    },
  "key9": "value9"
  }
```

And it should look like this when it's an array:

```
"link": [{
  "values": {
    "key1": "value1",
    ...
    "key8": "value8",

    },
  "key9": "value9"
  }]
```

EDIT -----------------------------
This is what I've written so far that is producing the type error I'm experiencing.

```
  const isLinkArray = sections.values;
  isLinkArray.link = Array.isArray(isLinkArray.link) ? isLinkArray.link : [isLinkArray.link];
```

EDIT 2 ---------------------------

The final answer ended up being almost identical to Kinglish' answer, so I figured I would post it here. The issue I ran into was that the JSON right above 'link' was also an array and that was causing the typescript error.

```
  const sectionsWithLinkArray = sections.map((section) => {
      return {
        values: {
          ...section.values,
          link: !Array.isArray(section.values.link) ? [section.values.link] : section.values.link,
        },
      };
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Array.isArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) to check, then convert

```js
let data = {
  "link": {
    "values": {
      "key1": "value1",
      "key8": "value8"
    },
    "key9": "value9"
  }
}

data.link = Array.isArray(data.link) ? data.link : [data.link];
console.log(data)
```

Comment: I get an error ```Property 'link' does not exist on type '() => IterableIterator<{ values: { link?:...```

Comment: Which I'm confused by, because clearly link is there, it says so in the error message. Is it because link is an optional part of the object?

Comment: Can you show in your question the block of code in question (the iterator)?

Comment: See above under EDIT

Comment: I figured out the issue. The JSON had another array of objects above where I was working and that was causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by writing a simple function that checks if it's an array.

```
const returnArray = (value) => {
  if (Array.isArray(value) {
    return value;
  }
  return 
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

updated the answer of @Kinglish to typescript one because you cannot change types of defined value as it giving error for this either simply ignore the typescript or define types that simply accept link in `object` and `array of object` or just created new `variable` that expect a link in the array and wrap it inside data by simply doing this:

```
const data = {
  link: {
    values: {
      key1: 'value1',
      key8: 'value8',
    },
    key9: 'value9',
  },
};

// This is the type of data you can't change it by default and it doesn't expect array of object of `link`.
// const data: {
//   link: {
//     values: {
//       key1: string;
//       key8: string;
//     };
//     key9: string;
//   };
// };

const linkArray = { link: Array.isArray(data.link) ? data.link : [data.link] };

// Now this is the type of linkArray that expect array of object of `link`
// const linkArray: {
//   link: {
//     values: {
//       key1: string;
//       key8: string;
//     };
//     key9: string;
//   }[];
// };


console.log('data', data);
console.log('linkArray', linkArray);
```